# xxHash convert resulting in hash too long

Tags: c#, arrays, bitconverter

I'm using `xxHash` for C# to hash a value for consistency.
`ComputeHash` returns a `byte[]`, but I need to store the results in a `long`.

I'm able to convert the results into an `int32` using the `BitConverter`. Here is what I've tried:

```
var xxHash = new System.Data.HashFunction.xxHash();
byte[] hashedValue = xxHash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(valueItem));
long value = BitConverter.ToInt64(hashedValue, 0);
```

When I use `int` this works fine, but when I change to `ToInt64` it fails.

Here's the exception I get:

> Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the exception that I get: "Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length."

Comment: How many bytes in `hashedValue`?

Comment: @DesmondNzuza hashedValue must be at least 8 bytes long to convert to `long`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a new answer because current implementation of xxHash from Brandon Dahler uses a hashing factory where you initialize the factory with a configuration containing hashsize and seed:

```
using System.Data.HashFunction.xxHash;

//can also set seed here, (ulong) Seed=234567
xxHashConfig config = new xxHashConfig() { HashSizeInBits = 64 };
var factory = xxHashFactory.Instance.Create(config);
byte[] hashedValue = factory.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(valueItem)).Hash;
```

Answer (score 8):

When you construct your `xxHash` object, you need to supply a hashsize:

```
var hasher = new xxHash(32);
```

valid hash sizes are 32 and 64.

See https://github.com/brandondahler/Data.HashFunction/blob/master/src/xxHash/xxHash.cs for the source.

Comment: @leppie: Yep, it's almost worth writing `var hasher = new xxHash((int)32);` so a casual inspection of the call-site is unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for the answer spender. I specified the hash size and that sorted the issue out for me. I did not want to have to check the resulting byte[] this does it for me. Thanks.

Comment: @DesmondNzuza Don't forget to check this answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

`BitConverter.ToInt64` expects `hashedValue` to have 8 bytes (= 64bits). You could manually extend, and then pass it.

Comment: I know the reason why it was failing was becuase the length is too short. I don't have the luxury to inspect or expand the resulting byte[] becuase I don't want to affect performance. Specifying a hash size did the trick for me. Thanks.